# Ionic + angular side menu is not showing on first page Load

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created one application using Ionic Side Menu. Issue is when first time page is loading menu button is not showing, but when I am reloading the page or navigation to another page then it's coming. Not able to find any solution.

```
<ion-app>
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
<ion-toolbar class="header-color">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button auto-hide="true"></ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>      
  <ion-title>
    Dashboard &nbsp;| &nbsp;<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
  </ion-title>      
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay" menuId="sideMenu" [content]="content">
<ion-content class="layered-image">
  <ion-list id="inbox-list">
    <ion-list class="user-box">
      <ion-list-header class="ion-text-center">
        <img id="profile-img" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="profile-img-card" />
      </ion-list-header>
      <div class="ion-text-center user-title">
        <div>Welcom, {{userName}}</div>
        <div class="logout"><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list auto-hide="true" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index" class="ion-list-remove-padding">
      <ion-item (click)="menuClick(i)" lines="none" detail="false">
        <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>           
        </ion-icon>
      </ion-item>          
    </ion-list>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<div class="ion-page" id="main-content" main>
   <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>   
 </div>
</ion-app>
```

---

First time load:

[image]

After Reload

[image: After Realod]

Comment: You need auto-hide="true"? Try removing it or setting it to false.

Comment: @1x2x3x4x tried all this no success.

Comment: Trye autoHide="false"